# How to store OpenGL Primitives in a tree data structure in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, data-structures, tree, glut

I'm new to OpenGL and C++. Say I start with a 2D square (on the very left) like shown in the picture below. I want to make it interactive with the `glutKeyboardFunc()` so when I press a number a new box will draw next to the corresponding edge.

[image]

Figure the best way to do this is to have a tree structure that hold all the boxes. But I'm not sure how I can hold basic primitives into a data structure, a tree, for instance.

I'm aware that I can only call the `glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay)` once, and the rest should handle by the `glutKeyboardFunc()`

Any help would be appreciated :)

**Update**: thanks for pointing out `glutPostRedisplay()` but what if I want to make the box selectable and keep tracking the current selected box with `glutMouseFunc()`, and from there when I add more boxes, I need to know how many child box it has created, so I can provide the right position when new box is drawn. Seems that makes more sense now to use a tree data structure ? Just not sure how I can store the information I need into a tree.

Comment: You can only call glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay) once but you can call glutPostRedisplay() as many times as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, you can make a class that represents the box, such as:

```
class Box {
public:
  void Move(int newx, int newy) {
    x = newx;
    y = newy;
  }
  void Resize(int newx, int newy) {
    w = newx;
    h = newy;
  }
  int getX() { return x; }
  int getY() { return y; }
  int getW() { return w; }
  int getH() { return h; }
private:
  int x, y, w, h;
};
```

Then, you can have a global vector to hold all the boxes:

```
#include <vector>

vector<Box> box;
```

You can then add a box like this:

```
Box newbox;
newbox.Move(40,50);
newbox.Resize(10,10);
box.push_back(newbox);
```

And move an existing one like this:

```
box[3].Move(70,20);
```

I'm sorry I cannot answer your question completely, but I hope you know have an idea on how to accomplish your project.

*EDIT:* To achieve a tree structure, you could add these variables to the Box class:

```
private:
  Box* parent;
  vector<Box*> child;
```

This would allow you to keep track of the tree structure. Then doing something like:

```
myBox->getChild(0)->getChild(1)
```

would retrieve the second child of the first child of myBox. I hope this makes sense to you.

Comment: that's okay, thanks for your help. I don't quiet understand how vector would work in this case? Hmm I was thinking about making a box class too, but not sure what should be included. Do you think I should put all the glVertex and other opengl function inside the class ? or should I leave it out

Comment: Leave it out. The Box class should manage itself, and the glKeyboard(), ect.. should handle the openGL stuff.

Comment: I implemented a bounding box hierarchy in C++ for my ray tracer a few years ago. This link might help you out, it has working code examples. As a disclaimer, it was academic (throw away) code. Now that I have been writing software professionally for a few years, it would be nice to go back and clean it all up. http://brian-stinar.blogspot.com/2008/04/acceleration-data-structure-bounding.html